# import excel file to java. Need file (not content)

Tags: java, excel, file, import, upload

i need import *.xls file to FILE object in java. I can read and write with no problems for local files but i need use classic "upload" file button.
I have form with some input-text and this input-upload.
I cant get FILE object in java to this *.xls.

With this works fine with locals... buy i need import from client.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\ant\\Descuentos.xls"));
```

Thanks

Comment: What _classic "upload" file button_, from what API ? Please provide more information. See [ask] to see what need to be found in a question

Answer (score -1):

In my experience you cannot assume for the file being available on the certain path "C:\..." on the clients side. This might be the cause. You should provide the client (user) the option to tell you where the xls is.

Comment: I think the idea is to upload a file from the client to the server into the folder `C:\\ant` but this is to broad for the moment. But this is more like a comment. you don't have an answer to this _broad_ question, wait to have the reputation to be able to comment ;)

Comment: sure. Its a hardcode for check the rest of funcional is fine. After it i need upload client file to get FILE object. But i dont know how get this file....